# Reading JSON file with Array

Tags: c#, json

I'm currently working on JSON string extraction using C#. My JSON string consist of an array with repetitive keys. Not sure if I'm describing it right since I'm new to this.

This is my JSON string

```
{"Index":
{   "LibraryName":"JGKing"
    ,   "FormName":"AccountsPayable"
    ,   "User":null
    ,   "FilingPriority":null
    ,   "FileDescription":null
    ,   "Fields":
            {"Field":
                [
                    {       "Name":"invItemID"
                        ,   "Value":"6276"
                    }
                    ,{      "Name":"invEntityCode"
                    ,       "Value":"16"
                    }

                    ,{      "Name":"invVendorCode"
                    ,       "Value":"MIRUB01"
                    }

                    ,{      "Name":"invNumber"
                    ,       "Value":"PWD5"
                    }

                    ,{      "Name":"invDate"
                    ,       "Value":"2017-08-21"
                    }

                    ,{      "Name":"invStatus"
                    ,       "Value":""
                    }

                    ,{      "Name":"invCurrencyCode"
                    ,       "Value":"AU"
                    }

                    ,{      "Name":"invCurrencyRate"
                    ,       "Value":"1"
                    }

                    ,{      "Name":"invTax"
                    ,       "Value":"454.3"
                    }

                    ,       {"Name":"invTotal"
                    ,       "Value":"4997.27"
                    }

                    ,       {"Name":"invReceivedDate"
                    ,       "Value":"2017-09-06"
                    }

                    ,{      "Name":"InvoiceLine1"
                    ,       "Value":"{\r\n  \"invLineNumber\": \"1\",\r\n  \"invPONumber\": \"\",\r\n  \"invPOLineNo\": \"1\",\r\n  \"invPOJobID\": \"\",\r\n  \"invCostCode\": \"\",\r\n  \"invCategory\": \"\",\r\n  \"invGLCode\": \"61-01-49-6862.517\",\r\n  \"invDescription\": \"\",\r\n  \"invEntryType\": \"\",\r\n  \"invAmount\": \"4542.97\",\r\n  \"invTaxAmount\": \"454.3\",\r\n  \"invTaxCode\": \"GST\",\r\n  \"invAmountIncTax\": \"4997.27\"\r\n}"}]}}}
```

I need to extract the value of invItemID key which is inside the array.
I tried to serialize my json string from a class but it returns null in the List<>

Here's my code

```
    public void CFExport(string jsonFile)
    {
        string ItemIDField;
        string ItemIDValue;

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(jsonFile))
            {
                JsonSerializer s = new JsonSerializer();
                var Idx = (JSONMain)s.Deserialize(r, typeof(JSONMain));
                var flds = (Fields)s.Deserialize(r, typeof(Fields));

                if (flds != null)
                {
                    foreach (var _field in flds.Field)
                    {
                        ItemIDField = _field.Name;
                        ItemIDValue = _field.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
    }


public class JSONMain
{
    public Index Index { get; set; }
}

public class Index
{
    public string LibraryName { get; set; }
    public string FormName { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string FilingPriority { get; set; }
    public string FileDescription { get; set; }

}

public class Fields
{
    public List<Field> Field { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use https://jsonutils.com to generate the classes and [Newtonsoft Json](https://json.net) for serialization

Answer (score 2):

Try to reflect the JSON file with your classes like this:

```
public class Index
{
    public string LibraryName { get; set; }
    public string FormName { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string FilingPriority { get; set; }
    public string FileDescription { get; set; }
    public Fields Fields { get; set; } //this line makes the difference
}
```

If you deserialize now, the fields should be populated automatically. I also advice you to use `JsonConvert.Deserialze<>()` since it is a bit easier (see [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)) and you are new to this topic.

Getting the value of `invItemID` could look like this:

```
public void CFExport(string jsonFile)
{
    string ItemIDField = "invItemID";
    string ItemIDValue;

    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(jsonFile))
    {
        var Idx = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONMain>(r);

        foreach(var field in Idx.Index.Fields.Field) 
        {
            if(field.Name == ItemIDField)
            {
                ItemIDValue = field.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whoohoo. My first answer on Stackoverflow! I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to extract the value of invItemID key which is inside the array.

You can retrieve value for your specified key `invItemID` from `Field` array by using `JObject`.

So you have no more need to manage classes for your json.

Here i created a console app for your demonstration purpose.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Get your json from file
        string json = File.ReadAllText(@"Your path to json file");

        //Parse your json
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

        //Get your "Field" array to List of NameValuePair
        var fieldArray = jObject["Index"]["Fields"]["Field"].ToObject<List<NameValuePair>>();

        //Retrieve Value for key "invItemID"
        string value = fieldArray.Where(x => x.Name == "invItemID").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        //Print this value on console
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + value);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}

class NameValuePair
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]